# What makes a GLM Hierarchical?

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, terminology, pymc

Wikipedia defines a Hierarchical GLM as:

> Hierarchical linear models (or multilevel regression) organizes the
>   data into a hierarchy of regressions, for example where A is regressed
>   on B, and B is regressed on C.

However, [PyMC](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/examples/GLM.ipynb) comes with a "Hierachical GLM" example defined as

`sat_t ~ spend + stu_tea_rat + salary + prcnt_take`

Why is this model hierarchical? Aren't we regressing `sat_t` on all the other variables **directly**? Or am I reading the definition or model specification incorrectly?

Here is the full code and result.

```
sat_data = pd.read_csv('data/Guber1999data.txt')
with Model() as model_sat:
    grp_mean = Normal('grp_mean', mu=0, sd=10)
    grp_sd = Uniform('grp_sd', 0, 200)

    # Define priors for intercept and regression coefficients.
    priors = {'Intercept': Normal.dist(mu=sat_data.sat_t.mean(), sd=sat_data.sat_t.std()),
          'spend': Normal.dist(mu=grp_mean, sd=grp_sd),
          'stu_tea_rat': Normal.dist(mu=grp_mean, sd=grp_sd),
          'salary': Normal.dist(mu=grp_mean, sd=grp_sd),
          'prcnt_take': Normal.dist(mu=grp_mean, sd=grp_sd)
    }
    glm.glm('sat_t ~ spend + stu_tea_rat + salary + prcnt_take', 
                    sat_data,
                priors=priors)
    trace_sat = sample(500, NUTS(), progressbar=False)

scatter_matrix(trace_to_dataframe(trace_sat), figsize=(12,12));
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "hierarchical" in this example means that it is a hierarchical Bayesian model.  It is not a hierarchical GLM in the sense you describe.

Comment: If you want an example of a hierarchical GLM that fits your definition you can check out my blog post on the Radon data set: http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2014/03/17/bayesian-glms-3/ (also uses pymc3).

Answer (score 4):

Ha! Wikipedia must be reflecting a fight for a cute term. What I am used to thinking as a"*hierarchical linear model*" is the model with observation units nested in a higher level units (students nested in classrooms, visits nested in patients, etc.), known also as a multilevel model ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model), [this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilevel-analysis) ) or a mixed model ([this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model)). The models have been around since at least [late 1980s](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/team/hg/), although the term "hierarchical linear model" has become more widely used after [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/076191904X) was published, and there is a software packages [by that name](http://www.ssicentral.com/hlm/).

The sequence of regression models is nothing new. Economists have been working with these [since 1950s](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1911287) under the name of "[simultaneous equation models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model)". The use of the term "hierarchical regression" to describe the system of regression equations has been on the rise only in the 2010s -- apparently with a generation of people who studied little statistics. If I were to see a simultaneous equation model referred to as a hierarchical regression as a reviewer, I would not stop at rejecting the paper, frankly. If you are propagating a wrong terminology, you are not helping the progress of science.